# javascript ternary opretor to fill a variable based on conditions

Tags: javascript, performance

I have this piece of code:

```
grp = $.cookies.get('grp');
if(grp == null){grp = 0}
```

1- how can i write it with ternary operators?
2- in word of performance is ternary form better or simple if statement if we have lots of them?

thanks in advance

Comment: `var grp = $.cookies.get('grp') || 0`

Comment: i'm sure your answer is write but unfortunatly its a comment not answer, any way thanks alot

Comment: @elclanrs using `||` means the condition cannot be `0` or `""` and can have a very undesirable outcome.

Comment: @Bart: It all depends, yes. But a cookie is either set or not, an empty cookie is not desirable either, and if it's `0` then it's `0`

Comment: @elclanrs That depends as well. `""` could be a valid value. It's best practice to always use the `===` to avoid type coercion. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: @Bart I like type coercion, you can use it to your advantage, in fact I use `==` more than `===`. If you have empty strings as valid values then something is wrong. Crockford has some valid points, but is not evil as he makes it seem. This very question has a legit use of type coercion (if unintentional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:

```
grp = $.cookies.get('grp');
grp = (grp == null) ? 0 : grp;
```

or

```
grp = $.cookies.get('grp') || 0;
```

I think the difference in performance is negligible, the important thing in such case is readability of the code.

Added: for example, if you want to check for object and create it if does not exist, then:

```
some_obj = window.some_obj || {};
```

Comment: can i put an object or an array instead of the string or number?

Comment: according to top comments how to use this method with something that is not a cookie?

Comment: @Homam see added answer, do you mean something like that ...?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid type coercion always use the `===` operator. The `null` check is discouraged as well. When a value is undefined javascript always returns `undefined`.

Most of the time it's easier to create a helper function to avoid repeated code.

```
var grp = defaultIfUndefined($.cookies.get('grp'), 'My default value');

function defaultIfUndefined (value, defaultValue) {
    if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks @bart but i think there is a misunderstanding of my question but the main concept for me is making the code shorter, more readable and more professional(i mean the best syntax available). my real code insisted of a cookie object that grp is only a little part of it, then there is no repeat for this part. anyway tnx again

Comment: This will work in this case, but not with undeclared variables, if you take this path the safest way is to check `if (typeof value === 'undefined'`). But I think this check is often unnecessary if you embrace type coercion.

Comment: @Homam Shorter is not the definition for professional, readable and maintainable code. On the contrary.

Comment: @elclanrs Good mention on the undefined check. Updated that. I know type coercion can be very useful but it can cause a lot of nasty bugs on the other.

Comment: Can't we use `$.extend` here ? :O